# Weird behavior of JS function "every()"

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, predicate

Please, can someone explain me behavior of function **every**.

I have an array and I want to apply function **every** to it. Function **every** is taking a predicate.

My simple predicate:

```
function test() {
  return function(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
    
    return true;
  }
}
```

I called function **every** on the array with my predicate:

```
const predicate = test();

[1, 2, 3].every(predicate);
```

Result:

```
Output:

1
2
3
```

BUT when I changed my predicate to this:

```
function test() {
  return function(...args) {
    console.log(...args);
    
    return true;
  }
}
```

The result is so weird for me:

```
Output:

1 0 [ 1, 2, 3 ] 
2 1 [ 1, 2, 3 ]
3 2 [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Why so? I expection somethin like this:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

```js
function test() {
  return function(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
    
    return true;
  }
}

function test2() {
  return function(...args) {
    console.log(...args);
    
    return true;
  }
}

const predicate = test();
const predicate2 = test2();
[1, 2, 3].every(predicate);
[1, 2, 3].every(predicate2);
```

Comment: You get passed in the value, the index, and the entire array. So if you log those all, `1 0 [ 1, 2, 3 ] ` is an expected output.

Comment: every has nothing to do. the calback's function signature works for `forEach`, `some`, `map`.

Comment: Note that you don't need to declare a function that returns a function (as you've done here with `test`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...arg` is like a passing of all the arguments that `.every` method accepts.

i.e. An array `element`, `index of the element` and a `whole array`.

Hence, to print values as an array. You can simply return the values in a square bracket.

Demo **:**

```js
[1, 2, 3].every(function(arg) {
  console.log([arg]);
  return true;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

every(), like map() and forEach(), calls function with two arguments: value and index.

Comment: They each have a third as well.

Comment: As @ScottSauyet said, there is a third argument. It's the array being iterated over.